# AhoyDTU Hoymiles - Wrong data rate?

Tags: ahoy

The connection between AhoyDTU and Hoymiles inverter is not stable. Sometimes everything ok for days, then not connection at all (RX no answer).

Status of NRF24L01+ is shown as connected. But data rate seems being not correct - I assume data rate should be 250 kbps.

Is there a way to set the data rate hard-coded?

[image: AhoyDTU - System]

Comment: The image link is broken. Please instead post the information as part of the post itself. It will help us help you better.